# File being copied into root directory as well as target directory

Tags: go, mux

I recently started working with Go and ran into a small problem. Below is my code for saving a file into the "./images" directory. While the code works and the files are being saved into "./images", the file is also being saved into the root directory of the project simultaneously. TL;DR: File is being saved twice (into root, as well as target) when it should only be saved once in the target directory

```
// Save
imageSave, err := os.Open(imageOutput.Name())
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

defer imageSave.Close()

dir := "./images"
dst, err := os.Create(filepath.Join(dir, filepath.Base(imageOutput.Name())))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer dst.Close()
defer imageOutput.Close()

_, err = io.Copy(dst, imageSave)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is `imageOutput.Name()` file?

Comment: It is the name of the file I am adding

Comment: This code copies the contents of a file on disk to another location on disk. Afterward, I would expect to have two copies of the file (the one at path `imageOutput.Name()` and the one at path `./images/...`). The code shown will not make any *more* copies than that.

Comment: I think you make a error where in the line io.copy. You name dst as the source and imageSave as the destination. While imageSave is the file you are reading.

Comment: @Dippo `os.Create` may not be an image source, it's empty

Comment: @zerkms Yes you are right, i wanted also to say that, but i think the question is wrong, but also, the code is confusing. So, fix the code, will fix the problem. Or, make the problem easier to understand.

Comment: @zerkms Also, i forgot to mention, the io,copy function is confusing. I would also think that you first need the source followed by the destination. But, it's the other way around. Silly mistake made by Google if you ask me.

Comment: @Dippo, I was going to say that io.Copy() takes destination first then source, then I saw your latest comment haha. The problem is that the file that I want to save (imageSave) is being saved in the root of the project folder *in addition* to the folder it is supposed to be saved in (./images). os.Create will create an empty file (dst) and io.Copy() will copy the contents of imageSave into dst.

Comment: @Sasank Ganapathiraju True, but the code is not correct. ImageSave is the source, while the name states it's the destination. If you rename it to imageLoad, it make more sense.

Comment: @Dippo Do you mean the variable names are confusing? or that the use of imageSave itself is causing the problem

Comment: @Sasank Ganapathiraju Yes, only confusing. If you rename it, you also see that the line with the file.Copy is not correct.

Comment: " (imageSave) is being saved' --- it's not "being saved" , it **already** is there.